# How to figure out what attribute I need to add and find out how to write them when I make a custom button & text field (also other UIs)

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm pretty new to Swift and want to ask a question about when we make a custom UI.

The image below is something I made today based on a tutorial video of how to make a custom UI.
[image]

and these are the codes for making the button and text fields.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupTextFeild()
    }
    
    
    private func setupTextFeild() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 30
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 6.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 8
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        clipsToBounds = true
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        
        textColor = .black
        backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.85)
        autocorrectionType = .no
        
        let placeholder = self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : ""
        
        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.darkGray])
        
        let indentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
        leftView = indentView
        leftViewMode = .always
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

here is another one

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    // for storyboard
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupButton()
    }
    
    
    func setupButton() {
        setShadow()
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        layer.cornerRadius = 30
    }
    
    
    private func setShadow() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 6.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 8
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        clipsToBounds = true
        layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

It seems ok for now but the problem is I just follow the code on Youtube and I don't think I can write those codes all by myself. Also, in the video, a guy didn't describe how he figured out writing, for example, like the code below

```
layer.cornerRadius = 30
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 6.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 8
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        clipsToBounds = true
        layer.masksToBounds = false
```

I want to know, for example, where the layer is coming from, why you know you need to write a layer first if you have to write code from scratch.

I kind of understand I need to put `layer.cornerRadius = 30` if I want to add a corner radius to my buttons, but is there any document saying I need to write like `layer.cornerRadius` in order to add corner radius (or how can I figure out I need to write like `layer.cornerRadius`)? I have no idea what properties I can write in my setupTextFeild() & setupButton() functions because I could not find any document describing attributes I can add when I make custom UIs. Is that something I should know when I write code in Swift or is there any document telling what properties I can add when making buttons, text fields e.t.c.

I think my English is not clear enough to tell the points I want to ask, but I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit difficult to answer so I may not explain the core of your question.
Programming is not something you can learn overnight. I myself have a massive amount to still learn about Swift and iOS. You don't need to know how to design a screen just because you watched a video doing one and copied it out. It's all part of the learning process. You can do Bootcamp courses online which will certainly help speed up your learning process but will still not make you a full-fledged developer that knows in the back of their mind how to do everything by heart.

Here is an example of how we currently learn something. My designer will give me a design like yours. I will attempt to create it. The moment I reach something I don't know, let's say, how to add a corner radius, I will google it. At that point, I will have learnt it and next time I will probably not have to research how to do it again. It's a slow learning loop that occurs throughout your career. As you build up knowledge, you will rely on outside resources less.

There's no point looking for documentation on "attributes I can add when I make custom UIs" because it's only limited by your imagination, you may want fancy shapes, shadows, colours etc. You will figure it out as your need arises.

I hope this rambling of mine makes some sense and that I answered part of your question at least.